# Is it valid to throw from a nested catch?

Tags: c++, exception

In the following example:

```cpp
try {
  fun1();
} catch (...) {
  try {
    fun2();
  } catch (...) {
    throw; // 2. Propagate potential exception in fun2()
  }
  throw; // 1. Propagate potential exception in fun1()
}
```

Is the statement in (2) going to trigger `std::terminate` ? I'm reading the documentation on [throw](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw):

> If any function that is called directly by the stack unwinding mechanism, after initialization of the exception object and before the start of the exception handler, exits with an exception, std::terminate is called. Such functions include destructors of objects with automatic storage duration whose scopes are exited, and the copy constructor of the exception object that is called (if not elided) to initialize catch-by-value arguments.

and I was wondering whether rethrowing is not a good idea when having nested try/catch blocks.

Comment: Neither `throw` in this code is "before the start of the exception handler".  They are safe.  Your quote is warning of exceptions thrown **before** the `catch`.

Comment: The key text is **and before the start of the exception handler**.  Once your are inside `catch` the *exception handler* has started.

Comment: The code has caught the exception at (2) so there is no longer unwinding in progress.

Comment: @RichardCritten was also struggling to understand how is the `throw` statement in (2) able to rethrow the correct exception. I guess what you say could explain it

Comment: I would enclose internal `try catch` in separate function. Then this doubt you have is less painful. Quote about terminate is about exception in flight. In practice this could happen when destructor throws exception when unwinding stack of other exception is in flight. That is why since C++11 all destructors are implicitly `noexcept`.

Comment: As written, nested try/catch is useless as `try { fun1(); } catch(...) { fun2(); throw; }` would do essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the quoted paragraph carefully:

> If any function that is called directly by the stack unwinding mechanism, after initialization of the exception object and before the start of the exception handler, exits with an exception

Once the outer `catch` block is entered, the exception handler has "started", so we are no longer in the "after initialization of the exception object and before the start of the exception handler" scenario. Therefore, this paragraph does not imply that `std::terminate` is called at `// 2`.

Of course, if there is no `try` block surrounding `// 2` that has a handler that's able to handle the exception, `std::terminate` will be called.

The OP also asked:

> was also struggling to understand how is the `throw` statement in (2) able to rethrow the correct exception.

Basically, there is a stack of exception objects that are being handled (they are not actually allocated on "the stack", but they form a stack in the sense of the data structure, *i.e.*, a LIFO queue). When the outer `catch` block is entered, the first exception is pushed onto the stack. When the inner `catch` block is entered, the second exception is pushed onto the stack. Then, when `throw;` is executed, the exception that's at the top of the stack is rethrown.

If the statement at `// 2` were not present, the second exception would expire at the end of its `catch` block and get popped from the stack. Then, at `// 1`, the first exception would be rethrown instead.

I'm not sure how compilers actually implement this stack, but conceptually, that's what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile to answer the question in the comments